# Checar soma exata em uma célula a partir de um range

Tags: microsoft-excel

Tenho um range no Excel com N valores. Tenho também uma célula com um valor x.

É possível sem usar vba, que eu saiba exatamente quais são as células nesse range que somadas, resultam no valor da minha célula em destaque?

Exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

As células em amarelo somadas, resultam exatamente na minha célula em destaque.

Comment: Penso que não é possível, no entanto pode ser que alguém explique melhor, agora estou curioso também. Pelo que percebi tu queres realizar várias somas do teu range (coluna) e verificar se é igual à tua coluna assinalada. É esse o teu problema?

Comment: Exatamente, Claudio!

Comment: O problema é que há dois números 23, então há duas respostas. Se não a utilização de um Solver (Programação Linear) seria o suficiente para realizar isto com um modelo simples. Porém com isto, o modelo se torna mais complexo, podendo se tornar não linear, porém continua solucionável sem a utilização de Excel VBA. @LucasAugusto há algum critério para a escolha do primeiro ou do segundo 23?

Comment: @danieltakeshi, fiquei curioso com sua proposta de solução. Na verdade a imagem é totalmente ilustrativa, acabei colocando o número 23 duas vezes sem perceber. Como seria a solução se existisse apenas 1 número 23?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Excel Solver

Para realizar estas tarefas sem a utilização do VBA, o solver precisa ser utilizado e uma lógica binária simples é utilizada.

### Habilitar o Solver no Excel

A versão utilizada é o Excel 2010.

1. Entre no botão Office ou Arquivo.
2. Clique em **Opções**.
3. Clique em **Add-Ins**.
4. Instale o Solver Add-in e clique em Ok.

### Habilitar o Add-in

1. [Habilite o Modo Desenvolvedor](https://support.office.com/pt-br/article/Mostrar-a-guia-Desenvolvedor-e1192344-5e56-4d45-931b-e5fd9bea2d45)
2. Na aba **Desenvolvedor**, clique em **Add-ins**
3. Uma janela irá abrir e o **Solver Add-in** deve ser marcado.

[image: Solver Add-in]

### Solução

1. Com os dados fornecidos no exemplo, as células `A1:A10` foram preenchidas.
2. A célula `B11` é preenchida com a fórmula `=SUMPRODUCT(A1:A10;B1:B10)` ou `=SOMAPRODUTO(A1:A10;B1:B10)`
3. Abra o Solver em **Dados**
4. Em **Set Objective**, selecione a célula `B11`.
   [image: Janela Solver]
5. Escolha a opção **Value of:** e insire o número de soma desejado.
6. Na opção **By changing Variable Cells**, escolha as células `B1:B10`.
7. Clique em **Add**.
8. Uma janela irá abrir e as células `B1:B10` devem ser escolhidas como referência. E a opção `bin` deve ser escolhida. Clique em Ok.
   [image: Add Constraint]
9. No método de solução escolha **Simplex LP**.
10. Clique em **Opções** e preencha conforme a imagem.
    [image: Opções]
11. Clique em Solve e depois Ok.
    [image: Resultado Solver]

### Resultados Solver

[image: Resultados Solver]

### Filtro

Após a solução do solver, inserir um filtro para o número `1`na coluna `B`.

## Resultado

Com o filtro podemos concluir que as linhas 3 e 4 são os coeficientes da soma.

[image: Resultado]

### Extra:

Para mudar a função de otimização, outras formas de função objetivo ou mais restrições podem ser adicionadas. Caso deseje se aprofundar no assunto procure por Programação Linear, Método Simplex ou Solver. Ou em inglês Linear Programming (LP), Simplex ou Linear Optimization. Uma boa ferramenta para o Excel de problemas de otimização é o [Solver Studio](http://solverstudio.org/).